# windows protect files from deletion by toddler

Tags: windows-7

I'm running windows 7 home premium and have a 2 year old who is starting to take a keen interest in it.

I have created a separate account and added passwords to the other accounts however I don't know the best way to prevent that user from accidentally deleting files - and it is surprising how quickly random bashing of a keyboard results in deleted files.

there is 1 administrator account, and two user accounts - one of which I want to prevent from being able to delete all my photos (which are in the public folder to allow access by all accounts).

Comment: Sorry. Question off topic here. Try in Superuser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is set security permissions on the folder.

1. Right click on the public folder and select properties.
2. On the security tab, add the toddler's user account by selecting the
   edit button in the top half of the window.
3. In the bottom half (with the toddler's account selected on top) you
   can change the permissions.  Check off the deny permissions so that
   the little one cannot do anything with the files. You may still want
   read access if you want to look at them from that account.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to folder properties then security tab and chose settings there

[image]

Comment: JKM Beat me to it :)

Comment: Even if someone "beat[s] you to [answering]", you can always make your answer *better* - screenshots are a good start, but it would be *good* if you could include more detailed steps, and *great* if you could provide screenshots demonstrating those steps.